# EPUB mimetype not showing on PHP (for uploading)

Tags: php, file-upload, epub

Im trying to upload an Epub file to my Website using PHP.
Now, i know that i need to check for the mime type like *'application/epub+zip'*
but the problem is that the mime type for the file doesn't show..
i have this code here to upload the file and print the file's details :

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
echo '<pre>';
echo "Type: " . $_FILES['userfile']['type'] . "<br />";
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "File is invalid, upload failed.\n";
}
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

But the result is :

```
File is invalid, upload failed.
[name] => xx.epub
[type] => 
[tmp_name] => 
[error] => 2
[size] => 0
```

The [type] property is empty thats why I get an error on the uploading... do i need to fix something on the php configuration? I'm still new on PHP so.. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i got it working somehow, i just tried running it again and it worked. That was somewhat weird. Anyway I'm closing this question.